# Experimental confirmation of tidal forces in the gravitational field

Tags: newtonian-gravity, tidal-effect

Are there any experimental confirmations of the tidal forces in a gravitational field?

Specifically I am interested in the following effect: consider two objects of mass $m$ with relative distance $x$ in the gravitational field of the earth, coupled via a harmonic potential

$$ R = \frac{1}{2}(r_+ + r_-) $$

$$ x = r_+ - r_- $$

$$ r_\pm = R \pm \frac{1}{2}x $$

$$ E_\text{kin} = \frac{m}{2}\left(\dot{r}_+^2 + \dot{r}_-^2\right) = \frac{(2m)}{2}\dot{R}^2 + \frac{(m/2)}{2}\dot{x}^2 $$

$$ E_\text{pot} = -GmM\left(\frac{1}{r_+} + \frac{1}{r_-}\right) + \frac{(m/2)}{2}\omega_0^2 (r_+ - r_-)^2 \simeq -\frac{G(2m)M}{R} + \frac{(m/2)}{2}\left(\omega_0^2 - \frac{2GM}{R^3}\right)x^2 $$

So we find a correction of the frequency $ \omega_0 \to \Omega_R $ due to the tidal forces via Taylor expansion of the gravitational terms $ r_\pm^{-1}  $ in $ x/R \ll 1 $ up to second order:

$$ \omega_0^2 \to \Omega_R^2 = \omega_0^2 - \frac{2GM}{R^3} $$

Has this effect been measured, e.g. at the ISS, e.g. via the vibrational spectra of di-atometic molecules?

Comment: Have you looked at the typical value of $\frac{2GM}{R^3}$ here and compared it to the typical uncertainty in frequency measurements?

Comment: No, I didn‘t. Do you know a reference?